# How to add template colors to custom block options in WordPress Gutenberg editor sidebar?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

Please have a look at the attached image for reference.

I am building a block based plugin for the Wordpress Gutenberg editor.

**How can I add template colors** (i.e., those black and pastel shades) **to `ColorPalette`** ("Input border color")**?**

Catch is that I do not want the toggle system ("Color Settings") that `PanelColorSettings` comes with.

The "input border color" is going to be part of a `PanelBody` that already has other settings that use stuff like `TextControl`.

I did some Googling and came across something called `withColors` - however that is just an HOC for `PanelColorSettings`. So I don't think that would solve my requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **How can I add template colors** (i.e., those black and pastel shades) **to `ColorPalette`** ("Input border color")**?**

In Gutenberg, you can get the [block color palette](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-support/#block-color-palettes) in two ways:

- Use [`getSettings()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#getsettings) in the block editor's data (`core/block-editor`). E.g.

  ```js
  import { select } from '@wordpress/data';

  const colorPalette = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSettings().colors;
  // PS: You can also run wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSettings().colors
  // via the console.
  ```
- Or particularly in a *function component*, use the [`useSetting` *hook*](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#usesetting) in the `@wordpress/block-editor` or `wp.blockEditor` package (which uses the `getSettings()` above). Note though, in WordPress 5.7, the hook [was named `useEditorFeature`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/05/27/whats-new-in-gutenberg-10-7-26-may/). So for example:

  ```js
  import { useSetting } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

  // Then in your EDIT FUNCTION, use useSetting( 'color.palette' ):
  const colorPalette = useSetting( 'color.palette' );
  ```

And just so that you know, in PHP, you can use [`get_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_support/) to get the above palette.

#### Example/Demo using the `useSetting` hook (in WordPress 5.8)

Note that in this example, I added the colors in the question (red, white and blue) and then the `color.palette` above.

1. In my `index.js` file, I got this at the top: (Note though, I omitted the `registerBlockType` stuff)

   ```js
   import {
       useBlockProps,
       InspectorControls,
       useSetting,
   } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

   import {
       PanelBody,
       TextControl,
       ColorPalette,
   } from '@wordpress/components';

   const CUSTOM_COLORS = [
       {
           color: '#f00',
           name: 'Red',
       },
       {
           color: '#fff',
           name: 'White',
       },
       {
           color: '#00f',
           name: 'Blue',
       },
   ];
   ```
2. And here's my `edit` function:

   ```js
   function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {
       const { content, borderColor } = attributes;

       return (
           <>
               <InspectorControls>
                   <PanelBody>
                       <TextControl
                           label="Content"
                           value={ content }
                           onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { content: value } ) }
                       />

                       <div>
                           <p>Input border color</p>
                           <ColorPalette
                               value={ borderColor }
                               colors={ [ ...CUSTOM_COLORS, ...useSetting( 'color.palette' ) ] }
                               onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { borderColor: value } ) }
                           />
                       </div>
                   </PanelBody>
               </InspectorControls>

               <div
                   { ...useBlockProps( {
                       style: {
                           border: '2px solid ' + borderColor,
                           padding: '10px 15px',
                       },
                   } ) }
               >
                   { content }
               </div>
           </>
       );
   }
   ```
3. So the above `InspectorControls` outputs this (the theme is Twenty Twenty-One 1.4 which has 10 colors in the block color palette — [see source on Trac](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentyone/1.4/functions.php#L202)):

   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: This works great, however you do end up with the color's HEX value. If the theme.json is updated, you'll still have the old color. I've been hoping to find a way to select a theme color and keep it linked to that color, in case theme.json is ever modified.